# Barrier potential for germanium, silicon and gallium arsenide

Tags: homework-and-exercises, semiconductor-physics

Where did the barrier potentials for Germanium (0.3V), Silicon (0.7V) and Germanium Arsenide (1.2V) come from? How was it derived?

Comment: Does "it was measured that way" count?

Comment: @KyleKanos That was what I was also thinking. But my professor asked us to find for the derivation of those potential barriers.

Comment: Do you mean the 'diode drop'? If so, the derivation is, well, not straightforward. Somewhere I have an answer that addresses that question...

Comment: are you sure it ain't "Gallium-Arsenide" rather than "Germanium-Arsenide"?

Answer (score -1):

the sorta ideal volt-amp equation for a simple PN junction is

$$ I = I_0 \left( e^{\frac{q V}{n k_B T}} - 1 \right) $$

where $q$ is the elementary charge, $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant and $T$ is absolute temperature. $-I_0$ is the reverse bias current and is very very small in magnitude.  the only way that $I$ gets to be something other than a very small current is if the exponential value $e^{\frac{q V}{n k_B T}}$ starts taking on some values much greater than 1 (or much greater than 2.718281828).  otherwise, we cannot tell that the diode has "turned on" or that the PN junction is forward biased.

so for $1 \ll e^{\frac{q V}{n k_B T}}$ it must follow that

$$ \frac{q V}{n k_B T} = \frac{V}{V_0} > 1 $$

by at least a few integer values.  $e^8$ is a pretty big number that, when multiplied by the tiny $I_0$, results in a measurable current.

so $V_0 = \frac{n k_B T}{q}$.  find out what those values are for Si, Ge, and Ga-As and compare their proportionality to the stated barrier potentials.  i would suggest that the barrier potential is proportional to $V_0 = \frac{n k_B T}{q}$.